# Why is there a resistor in this reverse-polarity-protection circuit?

Tags: resistors, reverse-polarity, 24v

I was looking at the recommended reference implementation for a particular integrated circuit (the TI SN65HVS880, [data sheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvs880.pdf)). It runs off of a 24 volt power supply. The circuit diagram looks like this (taken from page 17 of the data sheet, red added, with V24 being the IC's 24-volt power input):

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I am assuming everything between the 24 V power supply and the IC itself is protection circuitry and the BYM10-1000 diode is for reverse polarity protection. But I do not understand the purpose of the 56 ohm resistor (highlighted in red).

Why is the resistor there? Is it necessary?

A few further notes: The resistor must be rated to 1 amp or less (looking up the data sheets for "MELF" resistors, that's as high as they go) and the diode there is only rated to 1 amp. There was no further explanation of this circuit provided.

Comment: Did you see page 14?

Comment: Good lord, no, I did not! I must have gone through the data sheet a hundred times and I don't know how I missed that! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm betting on this as the reason:
[image: Applications: Sensor Inputs for Industrial Automation and Process Control]

In an industrial environment you will want the design to be somewhat ruggedized, and that's what this circuit does.

It protects the input from

1. Reverse-voltage (via BYM10-1000)
2. Overvoltage (via 56\$\Omega\$ and Z2SMB36)
3. High-voltage transients (via 56\$\Omega\$ and 2.2\$\mu\$F)

Comment: Could you explein why is the 2.2uF required to suppress HV transients? Wouldn't the Z2SMB36 do the job alone? And what is the 220nF/100V for?

Comment: Keep in mind that all of these components have little parasitic elements that become involved at very fast speeds. The diode has a capacitance that keeps it from reacting quickly. The capacitors have inductance that is usually larger the larger the cap. So, if you have a transient that has a super-fast rise time, the fastest part of the energy will be absorbed by the 220nF 60V, followed by the 2.2uF 60V. If that dumps enough voltage on those capacitors to exceed 36V, the diode will begin conducting after some time.

Comment: Based on the datasheet, this seems a little loose to me (absolute max input voltage says 35V) but perhaps someone at TI tested it.

Comment: And I do not know what the 220nF/100V capacitor is for.

Answer (score 3):

No rep for comment.

As shown, I would have put the 220nF 100V cap in parallel with the 2.2uF cap.

At present it forms a 1:11 voltage divider for high frequencies from the 24Vin input to the V24 pin of the IC, yet the purpose of the network is to isolate the IC from transients and noise on the 24Vin.  The diode and resistor will store very little inductive energy and should be fine without a snubber cap.

The full circuit on pg 15 of the data sheet shows a 220 nF cap in parallel with the 2.2 uF and also a parallel input filter of 36V transorb // 4.7nF // 220 nF.  This makes lots of sense.

But. I am still uncertain about the snubber across the reverse-polity protection diode.  I would have to look up the stored energy in the diode before I made a decision but the result might be 100pf just across the diode - or none at all.